# Issue while trying to install or update package using pip command

Tags: python, pip, sni

For some reason I can't use `pip` to install or update python packages in my system.
I get this error.

> Exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 209, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 299, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py",
>   line 360, in prepare_files
>       ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py",
>   line 448, in _prepare_file
>       req_to_install, finder)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py",
>   line 397, in _check_skip_installed
>       finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, self.upgrade)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py",
>   line 440, in find_requirement
>       all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py",
>   line 398, in find_all_candidates
>       for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py",
>   line 543, in _get_pages
>       page = self._get_page(location)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py",
>   line 646, in _get_page
>       return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py",
>   line 755, in get_page
>       "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 480, in get
>       return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py",
>   line 378, in request
>       return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 468, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 576, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py",
>   line 46, in send
>       resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 376, in send
>       timeout=timeout
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 559, in urlopen
>       body=body, headers=headers)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 345, in _make_request
>       self._validate_conn(conn)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 784, in _validate_conn
>       conn.connect()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 252, in connect
>       ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py",
>   line 296, in ssl_wrap_socket
>       cnx.set_tlsext_host_name(server_hostname)
>
> File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 423, in explode
>
> ```
> raise NotImplementedError(error)   NotImplementedError: SNI not available
> ```

I tried installing the packages `pyOpenSSL`, `ndg-httpsclient` and `pyasn1` manually but still the problem persists.

My system is a RED HAT 4.1.2(server) with Python 2.7.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You OpenSSL(not pyOpenSSL) is too old, you need to install an OpenSSL version that supports SNI.